# error for "module 'click.termui' has no attribute 'get_terminal_size'"

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I tried to upload my images to my object storage bucket but I got this error: "module 'click.termui' has no attribute 'get_terminal_size'". How can I fit it?

Someone mentioned that "use shutil.get_terminal_size" instead. But how should I change it? Thank you